# Duplicate rules created in GKE Ingress load balancer

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

Every time I add a new rule to the ingress, it creates multiple rules in the load balancer. The rules are basically the same, pointing to the same backend

Here is my ingress file:

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1beta1
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  name: ingress-test.wpspeedmatters.com
spec:
  domains:
    - ingress-test.wpspeedmatters.com
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: basic-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: wordpress-ip
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: ingress-test.wpspeedmatters.com
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: wordpress
    servicePort: 8080
  rules:
    - host: ingress-test.wpspeedmatters.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: wordpress
              servicePort: 8080
```

Here are the duplicate rules created in the load balancer:
[image]

Comment: I have the same problem, but it's even worse because I registered 2 wordpress services - prod and staging basically. I wanted to have them behind the same load balancer. But now staging.myhost.com points to both staging and prod service.

Answer (score 2):

By default, the [HTTP(S) Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/) will create two default rules: One that matches all the hosts and paths and another matching your current host `ingress-test.wpspeedmatters.com` and all paths.

Then, your custom path defined in the `Ingress` YAML (`/*`) will be added. In this case, it just happens that is the same as the second aforementioned rule, that makes it look as if they were repeated.

If you change it to `/something` instead of `/*`, you will still end up with 3 path rules. However, this time you'd have Host as `ingress-test.wpspeedmatters.com` and Path as `/something`, plus the other 2 default rules in the load balancer.

So it's basically the default load balancer rules plus your ingress custom rules.

Comment: talked to someone in Google and they said the same

Answer (score 0):

It becomes more apparent if you try to edit your Load Balancer manually. Of course you should not actually store any changes, but try the edit mode just to check the rules:
[image]

I was also using Ingress for Wordpress deployment and, what's more, tried to re-use the same Load Balancer/Ingress for both staging and prod env. I was shocked at first when I saw the duplucates, especially since the default service in my case was prod, so it seemed like staging by default would also point to prod.
But despite the awkward UI, everything works as expected.